# Why is there a spike in the output of this square wave oscillator I made using a 555 time with 50% duty cycle?

Tags: timer, 555

The wave form has a spike, what is causing it?

Would that spike create more harmonics than a waveform without the spike?

Scope shot of waveform:

[image]

Comment: Is that a **10X attenuator** probe?...could be adjusted improperly.

Comment: Is it a bipolar 555? They have a design feature where both the output transistors conduct. Use a cmos version and the problem should disappear.

Comment: This spike could be due to an unbypassed DC supply to the 555. Add a capacitor between pin 1 and pin 8.

Comment: We don't see how you are measuring it. It may simply be because your probes are not properly connected to the 555 output and ground. Also if you are using the probe in 1x mode then that will definitely be a problem.

Comment: When I probe pin-7 of the 555 the there is no spike but on pin-3 there is?

Answer (score 2):

Spikes like this are to be expected whenever one tries to create a square waveform.

They are either lived with or "softened" in one way or another (sacrificing the pretty look of the waveform), depending on circumstances.

Why these things happen?

First, there is no such thing as a vertical part of the waveform. The circuits have limited slew rate so the switch between the two voltages always happens in a finite time.

Second, the ideal, theoretical square waveform is extremely rich in high-frequency harmonics. No signal path could be made with ideal frequency response so you will always be able to see artifacts of losing or distorting some high-frequency components.

"Overshots" like yours are usually unwanted and the general approach against them is to use low-pass filter in the signal path. The leading edges will become somewhat round, but the voltage will stay between the expected bounds.

---

In a lot of cases, the real waveform could be better or worse than what you see on the scope because the scope itself, as an electronic device, has limited parameters.